# Using log4javascript - is there a way to apply a Level to a group?

Tags: log4javascript

I am using `log4javascript` and want to be able to apply a `Level` to a group.

I currently have a `PopupAppender` that has a threshold of `WARN`.  However, it is triggered whenever I create a group.

I am looking for a `group` function that takes a `Level` parameter like the `time` function does.

Is this implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, groups don't have a level. I may look into it for log4javascript 2.0.